# Morgan logs the requests after the router is invoked

Tags: node.js, express, morgan

I expect that Morgan first catch the request and log it (for example `GET /home 200`) and then, if I've a console log inside the home router, print it.

`Router.get("/home", (req, res) => { console.log("router invoked!" });`

And this happens on the Terminal:

`router invoked!
GET /home 200`

Shouldn't be printed upside down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Morgan is designed to log *when the response is sent*. It does this so that it can include relevant information from the response - for example, the response status code.

You can turn off this behavior by initializing it with the `immediate` option set to `false` ([documentation here](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#immediate)), but, as mentioned above, you will only be able to log the request and not the response.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to log both? Request so that I know when the request started and it's always being logged even if it crashes somewhere inside. Response for the extra info and response time. Or is it a bad idea to log both?